# PSObject cast to List<String>

Tags: c#, list, powershell, serialization

Handle the PSObject in C#
For command :

> Get-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter -All

One of the Response Object :

> IPv4Addresses                              : {12.12.12.12}

Serialized data :

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Deserialized.System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</T>
      <T>Deserialized.System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <LST>
      <S>192.168.11.22</S>
    </LST>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

I want to get the

```
<LST>
          <S>192.168.11.22</S>
</LST>
```

as

> `List<String>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use any xml parser for this. I will prefer linq to xml.

```
var xml=XElement.Load(xmlFilePath);
var nsManager=new XmlNamespaceManager(new XmlNameTable());
nsManager.AddNamespace("ns1",@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04");
var list=xml.XPathSelectElements("//ns1:LST/ns1:S",nsManager)
             .Select(element=>element.Value);
```

PS: You need to add `System.Xml` ,`System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml.XPath` namespaces in the `using` statements.